# openai.APITimeoutError: Request timed out. when trying to implement with dialogflow(ES)

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, chatbot, openai-api, timeouterror

I want to integrate opeai api with my chatbot built with Dialogflow(ES) But I Keep getting a timeout error how do I fix it?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from openai import OpenAI

app = FastAPI()
# openai_api_key = os.environ.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')
client=OpenAI(api_key="########",)

messages = []
@app.post('/')
async def webhook(request: Request)->dict:
    payload = await request.json()
    intent=payload['queryResult']['intent']['displayName']
    question=payload['queryResult']['queryText']

    if intent=="StressManagementTips":
        messages.append({"role": "user", "content": question})

        chat_completion=client.chat.completions.create(messages=messages,model="gpt-3.5-turbo",timeout=2,
                                                       max_tokens=75,temperature=0.7,top_p=0.9,frequency_penalty=0,presence_penalty=0.6)



        reply = chat_completion["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]


        return JSONResponse(content={"fulfillmentText":reply})


is there anything wrong with my code?
```

I want to identify intents and send the question to the backend and generate an answer. It shouldn't be too long that's why I have some parameters. Can someone help me fix it? Thank you

```
Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, State: URL_TIMEOUT, Reason: TIMEOUT_WEB.
```

Comment: Webhook fulfillment has a 5-second timeout limit. [Dialogflow Essentials webhook times out with DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/dialogflow-essentials-webhook-times-out-with-deadline-exceeded-error-000004640)